# A coordinate proof that every polygon with a circumscribed circle is convex

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Suppose that we have a polygon $P$ whose vertices are $z_1, z_2,..., z_n$ inscribed in a circle $C$ in the Cartesian coordinate system. Furthermore, suppose that along the perimeter of the circle, $z_1$ is adjacent to $z_2$, $z_2$ is adjacent to $z_3$, ..., and $z_n$ is adjacent to $z_1$ (but it may happen that for instance the line segment determined by $z_1$ and $z_2$ is not an edge of $P$). We must prove that indeed every line segment determined by each pair of adjacent vertices is an edge which will prove the convexity of $P$ (which follows by using the cartesian equation of $P$).
Toward a contradiction suppose that for example the line segment determined by $z_1$ and $z_2$ is not an edge of $P$. For some $i$ and $j$ (which may be the same) different from 1 and 2 we have that the line segment $l_1$ determined by $z_1$ and $z_i$, and the line segment $l_2$ determined by $z_2$ and $z_j$ are edges of $P$. 
$l_1$ and $l_2$ cannot “cross eachother” (this notion can be made more precise by using the polar coordinates of the vertices) since that would contradict the hypothesis that $P$ is a polygon. Accordingly, $the$ other edge $e_1$ incident on $z_1$, and the other edge $e_2$ incident on $z_2$ cannot cross eachother. Since $P$ is a polygon, there must be a chain of edges from $z_1$ to $z_2$. But any edge chain from $z_1$ to $z_2$ either leads to two edges crossing each other, or leads to one vertex having three incident edges, contradicting the fact that $P$ is a polygon.

Is this proof correct?

(I had posted this proof for [Proof that every polygon with an inscribed circle is convex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4889/proof-that-every-polygon-with-an-inscribed-circle-is-convex?rq=1) by mistake as that question addresses a polygon with an $inscribed$ circle. If this coordinate proof is correct (or not), I think one can provide a similar coordinate proof for that question as well.)

Comment: What in the hypotheses forbids a twisted square? If you don't **assume** that $z_{i}z_{i+1}$ is an edge for all $i$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier The answer lies in *"l1 and l2 cannot “cross eachother” since that would contradict the hypothesis that P is a polygon"* (that does not mean I agree with this, but one can add this constraint to a polygon anyway).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I see, thanks. I had not read further since I already did not seem to understand the statement.

Comment: As is, the proof does not work. The last sentence is far from obvious: the path may cross somewhere, but you have not proved this, your are merely assuming it.

Comment: I did not assume it. It is easily provable @Jean-ClaudeArbaut

Comment: Then prove it..

Comment: Anyway, I did not mean to ask this question. As I had added to my post, my intention was to solve that question posted by another member using coordinates